# Is $f(n)=\frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)+1}{4}$ surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{Z}$. By definition this map is surjective, if $\forall z\in\Bbb{Z}\exists n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=z$. The direct proof means I need to show the equation $$f(n)=\frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)+1}{4}=z$$

has a solution for each $z$, which I don't think is possible. Assuming the contradiction didn't help either? Ideas? I strongly believe this map is surjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $z \geq 1$ we have $f(2z)=z$. Also $f(2z+1)=-z$ for $ z  \geq 1$.  And $f(1)=0$ so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Your second sentence is the same as the first one. You did not cover the negative integers. Instead note that if $k\geq 0$, $f(2k+1)=-k$ and if $k\geq 1$, $f(2k)=k$.

Comment: @Gary Oops! Thanks.